# .desktop WINE -- open file in running program

Tags: ubuntu, wine, .desktop

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm running a text editor under WINE and am trying to figure how to add the ability to right-click on a text file in a file manager and have it open in that text editor, or at least make it part of the options.

I already have the following to start the editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NoteTab Pro
Comment=Create and edit text files
Exec=wine "/home/lee/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/NoteTab 7/NotePro.exe"
Type=Application
MimeType=text/css;text/csv;text/html;text/plain;
```

I couldn't find an existing answer; if there is one, point the way!

Comment: This would be more proper on AskUbuntu. If you're using Files (previously Nautilus), the default filemanager with the Gnome desktop which is the Ubuntu default, [this howtogeek article](https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/add-shortcuts-to-right-click-context-menu-in-ubuntu/) should be able to at least get you pointed in the right direction. No desktop environment to test this myself or I'd figure it out and post a real answer.

Comment: That's fine w/me. The moderator can move this to AskUbuntu.

Comment: Not actually sure if this would be more fitting there or not, now that I look again. Considering they both have Ubuntu and Wine tags it likely doesn't matter. I'm sorry, I will try to be less robotic. Lol.

Comment: File moved to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259721/desktop-wine-open-file-in-running-program